# can this multiple self-JOIN be optimized?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

Sorry if the title isn't clear enough.
This is my query:

```
SELECT
    '>200000 €' as amount,
    Q1.asset as inbound,
    Q2.asset as outbound,
    Q3.asset as inside
FROM
    (
    SELECT COUNT(amount* base_rate) as asset
    FROM user_wallet_movement
    WHERE status = 'execute'
        AND direction = 'inbound'
        AND to_address is null
        AND mov_date > '2020-01-07'
        AND mov_date < '2021-06-30'
        AND amount* base_rate > 200000
        ) AS Q1
JOIN
        (
    SELECT COUNT(amount* base_rate) as asset
    FROM user_wallet_movement
    WHERE status = 'execute'
        AND direction = 'outbound'
        AND to_address is null
        AND mov_date > '2020-01-07'
        AND mov_date < '2021-06-30'
        AND amount* base_rate > 200000
        ) AS Q2
JOIN 
        (
    SELECT COUNT(amount* base_rate) as asset
    FROM user_wallet_movement
    WHERE status = 'execute'
        AND to_address is not null
        AND mov_date > '2020-01-07'
        AND mov_date < '2021-06-30'
        AND amount* base_rate > 200000
        ) AS Q3
```

as you can see, I'm joining three queries which have some conditions in common.
My question is:
Is it possible to write only once the common conditions?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what the query should be doing.

Comment: On a side note: according to the SQL standard this query is invalid. `JOIN` is short for `INNER JOIN`, and an inner join requires an `ON` clause. Replace `JOIN` with `CROSS JOIN` in your query to get this straight. Then, you shouldn't be using string literals for dates, but date literals. That is as easy as to replace `'2020-01-07'` by `DATE '2020-01-07'`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner in MySQL default setups, `JOIN` without an `ON` condition produces a cross product without any questions asked.

Comment: @Kaii: Yes , MySQL lets you write invalid queries. This doesn't mean that you should do so. Explicit joins were invented for a reason. When seeing a comma separated join without a join criteria in the where clause, one could never tell whether this was on purpose or not. With explicit joins you can. Unless a stupid DBMS allows JOIN without ON of course :-)

Comment: Sorry to all of you. Unfortunately I'm still new in MySQL and I'm still learning stuff. I'm still practice with Joins and still learning all the differences. So thank you for your explainations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The intention of your example query is unclear to me, so my answer might not produce the results you are looking for. I am confused why `COUNT()` and not `SUM()` is involved.*

In any case you can apply conditional aggregation because all values come from the same table. No JOINs needed here.

If you are trying to **count** all transactions that are `> 200000` over some different criteria you can do:

```
SELECT
    '>200000 €' as amount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN direction = 'inbound' AND to_address is null 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS inbound,
    SUM(CASE WHEN direction = 'outbound' AND to_address is null 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS outbound,
    SUM(CASE WHEN to_address is not null 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS inside
FROM user_wallet_movement
WHERE 
    (amount*base_rate) > 200000
    AND status = 'execute' 
    AND mov_date > '2020-01-07'
    AND mov_date < '2021-06-30'
```

And if you want the total SUM of all transactions and also subtotals over inbound/outbound/inside you can do:

```
SELECT
    SUM(amount*base_rate) as total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN direction = 'inbound' AND to_address is null 
        THEN amount*base_rate ELSE 0 END) AS inbound,
    SUM(CASE WHEN direction = 'outbound' AND to_address is null 
        THEN amount*base_rate ELSE 0 END) AS outbound,
    SUM(CASE WHEN to_address is not null 
        THEN amount*base_rate ELSE 0 END) AS inside
FROM user_wallet_movement
WHERE 
    AND status = 'execute' 
    AND mov_date > '2020-01-07'
    AND mov_date < '2021-06-30'
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need.
I don't want to sum because I only want to know "how many time it happens" and not the sum of all of those amounts. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` expression

```
select
    '>200000 €' as amount
    sum(case when direction = 'inbound' then amount* base_rate else 0 end) as inbound_asset,
    sum(case when direction = 'outbound' then amount* base_rate else 0 end) as outbound_asset,
    sum(case when direction = 'execute' then amount* base_rate else 0 end) as execute_asset
FROM user_wallet_movement
WHERE to_address is not null
AND mov_date > '2020-01-07'
AND mov_date < '2021-06-30'
AND amount* base_rate > 200000
```